# Gradle do not shrink res by min api

Tags: android, gradle

I got a project with min api 14. 
AS version is 2.2.3. 
Gradle version is 2.2.3.
After generate signed apk file in res folder i got this subfolders

[image]

I guess folders with name ends v-4,v-11,v-13 should not be in the project.